# Import data in mysql table through CSV using php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am uploading data in my MySQL table through CSV. Total number of rows is less than 300 but in my MySQL table only 85 rows are importing and the rest are skipping. Where I am doing wrong. Any help would be highly grateful. Here is my code:

```
$con = getdb();
if(isset($_POST["Import"])){

    $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];      

    if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0) {
        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
        $i=0;
        while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

            $import="INSERT into customer
                                (id,name,email,flag,file)
                         values('".$data[0]."','".$data[1]."',
                                '".$data[2]."','".$data[3]."',
                                '".$data[4]."')";
            $get_data =  mysqli_query($con,$import) 
                                or die(mysql_error());

            if(!isset($get_data))
            {
                echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                        alert(\"Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File.\");
                        window.location = \"show.php\"
                      </script>";       
            } else {
                echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                    alert(\"CSV File has been successfully Imported.\");
                    window.location = \"index.php\"
                    </script>";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

and here is a screenshot of my csv file:

[image]

Comment: have you got any data in `$data` variable?

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: Please edit your post and add a couple of sample CSV lines. Without knowing how the sample data looks like, it seems that your `while`-loop doesn't run through all of your 300 CSV lines.

Comment: I see that code is basically a copy of the manual example. Did you check that your lines were < 1000 bytes long?

Comment: yes I checked it less than 1000 bytes and I also check by increasing the bytes but no luck

Comment: I edit my question and attached a screenshot of my csv please check

Comment: `die(mysql_error())` should be `die(mysqli_error())` - you can't mix the two libraries. Possibly you're not seeing errors due to this typo. Also you might want to consider using parameterised queries - it'll be more robust. Right now you might have syntax issues if any of your CSV data includes things like single quotes.

Comment: "attached a screenshot of my csv"...actually the raw CSV data (i.e. text) would be much more informative. If you open the CSV in a text editor you can see it, and paste it in here. It would be helpful to include the first line which fails to import, and maybe a line or two before and after that line.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

 $con = getdb();

    if(isset($_POST['Import'])){

        $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];      


         if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
         {
            $file = fopen($filename, "r");
            $i=0;
            while(($gdata = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE){

    $import="INSERT into customer(id,name,email,flag,file)values('".$gdata[0]."','".$gdata[1]."','".$gdata[2]."','".$gdata[3]."','".$gdata[4]."')";
   $get_data =  mysqli_query($con,$import) or die("can't".mysqli_error($import));



            }

        }

 fclose($file);
    }
 ?>
```